# Python timeseries datasets with different length to merge

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two timeseries datasets that I would like to merge. The only problem is that one is shorter than the other due to their difference in their incremental steps. i.e, one is increasing by 20 mins, and the other is every hour.

I would like to keep the 20 mins one as is, but repeat the one hour one so that they match.

I would like to use python, even though I am a novice user. Any help will be much appreciated. If its possible with Excel, then even better.

examples:
Dataset1:
TripStartDate   TripStartTime   BusStopSequenceNr   BusStationID
17/06/2018      08:45:00           21790             1134
17/06/2018      08:45:00           21810             1168
17/06/2018      09:55:00           21801             1173
17/06/2018      09:55:00           21803             1177
17/06/2018      09:55:00           21810             1168

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Gte.png)

Dataset2:
Time       Rain(mm)
2017010100  0.14
2017010101  0
2017010102  0
2017010103  0
2017010104  0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWWEJ.png)

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! You mention 20 mins and later 15 mins? Typo? Can you please provide some sample data (not as Image!). Paste a small sample of data and what you expect to be the outcome. More info here: [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It was a typo. The 20 mins was for illustration purposes, but it could be anything.
Adding the examples to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely merge the two, but you have to understand that at different frequencies this means that you will be missing data, and they will only have values where they overlap.

You can then use interpolation to fill in values.

```
A.merge(B, left_on='date', right_on='date', how='inner')
```

try this